# Map inside Panorama moves the panorama when panning map

Tags: windows-phone-7

Well basically, I have this bing map control inside my Panorama view, when I pan left or right, the panorama changes columns. Is there a way to avoid this?

[Video of behavior](http://www.screencast.com/users/CarloDekstop/folders/Jing/media/d4e1ec70-9103-4c39-ac1f-4150fea94dc4)

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a property on the Panorama to 'lock' it in place temporarly?

Comment: @Nate Bross: Not sure, I'll look for that, let me know if you have more info on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's advisable to not use the map in a panorama for this reason. If you are able to lock the map, then Jobi's suggestion should work for you.

This from Jeff Wilcox for reference:

*- "Using a map control inside a Panorama or Pivot is not recommended for a number of UX and technical reasons. Navigate to a subpage.*"

Comment: I'll keep this in mind. For now I'll keep in the panorama (in case Jobi's answer works), but I'll see what we can do about moving it from there.

Comment: You're right, it's not a good idea at all, it doesn't even look good! We'll change the overall layout of the app, when we started it we were just guessing how it should look, now we took a look at other apps, and we realized the design is not very WP7 compliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IsEnabled=False on the Map will do the trick Provided you don't need to manipulate that map you show in the Panorama

Comment: I'll give it a shot in a minute. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't read right. I do have to manipulate the map. This won't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Put the map within your own control or make a control that inherits from the map (if possible).

Then in the Control's code-behind file, put this. It worked for me:

```
    protected override void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnManipulationCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Control_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Control_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```