# Windows phone, poor performances in bing map

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a pivot windows phone 7 app on which  there is a bing map with 300 pushpins. When the user tries to pinch the map, the refresh time in my Lg optimus7 is really long and performances are poor.
Is there anything i can do to solve the problem or 300 pins are a number to avoid and i need to find another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the design guidelines states that you shouldn't use a Bing Map Control on a Pivot nor on a Panorama Control. This is due to the fact that both controls respond to touch and tend to interfere with each other. See: [Map inside Panorama moves the panorama when panning map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199232/map-inside-panorama-moves-the-panorama-when-panning-map)

So my solution was to move the map to a single page/form. Others have suggested (just google for those) to disable hittest on the map (making it read-only) but I do not like the messing with expected behavior.

300 pushpins might be a problem too but by (temporarily) moving the map to a separate form you will be able to find out what is slowing it down.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, i'll try to move my map on a new page.

Comment: +1 for showing fewer pins. Only add pins which can be seen to the map (and update as the user pans & zooms). If the user zooms right out then trying to make sense of 300 pins on a small screen will also not be realistic.

Comment: sure, i need to pin almost 300 cities on a world map; if the user zooms out at the highest level there is a lot of confusion, but cannot find a better way (ok, i could pin the country) to do it.

Comment: @Cris - I'd expect the map control to optimize out the invisible pins. However, determining the visibility of 300 pins can be costly 30 times per second.