# Disabling swipe in my webviews for my panorama to get it

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm beggining at coding on WP7.

For my first app on this platform, i don't have much to do, just creating a panorama which displays webviews in each of its items.

My problem is that I want the horizontal swipe gesture to be recieved by my panorama, and the rest of the touch event by my webviews.

Would anyone have an idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you seen this for tips on solving your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199232/map-inside-panorama-moves-the-panorama-when-panning-map

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure I understand, it is said there that I must not use horizontal scroll items in panoramas ? But the problems are inversed there. (I'm sorry for my writting, I am also beggining in english :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I don't think anyone has found a way to host a `WebBrowser` within a Panorama or Pivot. See the following questions for example:

[Map inside Panorama moves the panorama when panning map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199232/map-inside-panorama-moves-the-panorama-when-panning-map)

[WP7 Pivot control and a WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417293/wp7-pivot-control-and-a-webbrowser-control)

The best I have managed so far is to [suppress pan and zoom for a WebBrowser control](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/) - but I haven;t found a way to re-route the touch interactions to the hosting Panorama / Pivot.

Comment: I was visiting numerous post talking about just my problem, and I suppose you're right.. I'm a bit surprised that noone has yet wrote a classe extending panorama that always gets horizontal swipe events, and disable it to every child views